# How to insert a variable inside an AWS policy in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-policies

I have a policy defined in terraform for AWS resources like so:

```
device-status-policy = <<EOF
{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "iot:Connect", "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:foobaraccountid:client/device-status-qa*" }, { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "iot:Publish", "iot:Receive", "iot:Subscribe" ] }
   EOF
```

I would like Resource part of it to be a variable, like so (psuedo-code)

```
device-status-policy = <<EOF
{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "iot:Connect", "Resource": "$SOMEVAR/device-status-qa*" }, { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "iot:Publish", "iot:Receive", "iot:Subscribe" ] }
   EOF
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

String interpolation using the `${ ... }` syntax is the smallest change from a literal JSON string, but it runs the risk of challenges with producing correct JSON syntax if e.g. the strings being inserted contain backslashes and quote marks that the JSON parser could misinterpret.

Terraform's `jsonencode` function can be a good compromise, because Terraform has an object syntax that is very similar to JSON and thus the ability to quickly understand what JSON structure it's producing is preserved while at the same time allowing arbitrary Terraform expressions, whose results will be automatically encoded using correct JSON syntax:

```
  device-status-policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iot:Connect",
        "Resource": "${SOMEVAR}/device-status-qa*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [ "iot:Publish", "iot:Receive", "iot:Subscribe" ]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Note that the above is using a variant form of the Terraform language object syntax which uses colons instead of equals signs; both are valid, and using colons here helps the input resemble JSON and therefore makes it easier to adapt JSON you already wrote (as I did here) without a lot of rewriting.

However, the `"${SOMEVAR}/device-status-qa*"` sequence is understood by Terraform as a quoted template expression rather than as a literal string, and so it will evaluate `SOMEVAR` and include the result in the `Resource` value *before* serializing the whole resulting string using JSON syntax. Although it seems unlikely in this particular case, if the `SOMEVAR` result were a string containing a `"` then the JSON encoding would automatically escape it as `\"` to ensure that the result is valid syntax.

For larger data structures where it improves readability to factor them out into a separate file, [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) documentation includes some examples of [calling `jsonencode` from inside an external template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template) too, with similar results.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain all of it. I have marked this as the answer.

Comment: There is a specific data source for defining AWS IAM policies via HCL, that I would recommend over `jsonencode`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html

Comment: @MarkB's link seems to have broken. See: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document

Answer (score 7):

So the only reasonable option I would go for is the following:

Create a file e.g. policy.tpl with the following content:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "${SOMEVAR}/device-status-qa*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That policy file has the variable you need.

Then you simply reference it and pass the variable in the following way:

```
device-status-policy = templatefile("file.tpl", { SOMEVAR = var.your_terraform_variable})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Why would you consider this the only reasonable option? Why not use https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html

Comment: Data source is another resource you have to configure. Even though it works, many times it is detecting changes when performing terraform plan when in fact it is unchanged. With templetefile approach/function that has been introduced in TF 0.12, you don’t get that issue and for me it is a cleaner way of passing in parameters.

Comment: That's not how this data source works at all. It isn't reading an external resource at all. It is just a way to define AWS IAM policies inside HCL.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$SOMEVAR` to `${SOMEVAR}`.

Please review the [Terraform string interpolation syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html).

Also, I highly recommend using the data source [aws_iam_policy_document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) to define IAM policies, instead of here docs.